# WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public String userLog(
    Model model,
    @ModelAttribute("password") String password, 
    @ModelAttribute("username") String username,
    @ModelAttribute("token") String token) {
                        
    PasswordResetToken passToken = null;
    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(token)){
        passToken = userserv.getPasswordResetToken(token);
        if(passToken == null) {
            String message = "Invalid Token.";
            model.addAttribute("message", message);
            return "redirect:/badRequest";
        }
            
        User user = passToken.getUser();
        username = user.getUsername();
        UserDetails userDetails = userSecurityService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    
        Authentication authentication = new 
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());                       
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);       
        model.addAttribute("user", user); 
            
    } else {
    
        UserDetails userDetails = userSecurityService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);       
        model.addAttribute("user", userDetails); 
    }
    return "redirect:/profile";
}
```

How do I display a username of the session context holder in thymeleaf?

When I use these live.

```
<h2 class="section-headline h2"><span th:text="${user.username}"></span></h2>
```

I get error.

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Aug 18 14:01:28 EAT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/users/profile.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/users/profile.html]") etc.
```

But when I remove the line then it works well but without displaying the details of the person logged in.

Please help

Comment: Can you proof-read the question once & modify it, I am not able to understand?

Comment: 1. Use Spring Security (currently you are working around Spring Security), 2. use the proper Thymeleaf libraries to integrate with Spring and Spring Security.

Comment: Thank you  M.Deinum. I working on login page. So the login is working but I want once I login, for me to be able to see my username , first name and lastname etc.